# How to save the custom field data in payment section magento 2 to payment related table?

Tags: magento2, payment, additional-information

I am trying to save the payment related custom data in `additional_information` column through my custom module.can any one help me on this. 
Observer class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;

class PaymentAssignData implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        //die(__METHOD__);
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $addInfo = $order->getPayment()->getData();
        var_dump(json_encode($addInfo));
        exit;
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        var_dump(json_encode($observer));
        exit;
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $order->setDeliveryDate($quote->getDeliveryDate());





        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        //$quote = $order->getQuote();
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_data');
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        // $postData = $this->_request->getParam();;
        var_dump($payment);
        exit;
        // var_dump($quoteId);exit;

}
}
```

additional field in payment section.that fields are for all payment method.
js file

```
  define(
        [
            'ko',
            'jquery',
            'uiComponent'
        ],
        function (ko, $, Component) {
            'use strict';
            return Component.extend({
                defaults: {
                    template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/formdata-form',
                    taxCode: '',
                    taxState: ''
                },
                initialize: function () {
                    this._super()
                            .observe(
                                    [   'taxCode',
                                        'taxState'
                                    ]
                                    );
                    return this;
                },
                getData: function () {
                    return {
                        "additional_data": {
                            'tax_code': this.taxCode(),
                            'tax_state': this.taxState()
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }
);
```

Comment: Add new column in desired table through install script , and use plugin or event to insert data in that table . if you can more precise when you want to save i can tell you probable event as well

Comment: which event should i use to save the data.

Comment: How to get the custom field data to the observer to set data.

Comment: When are you trying to save data ?

Comment: i am using "sales_order_save_before" this event to saving the data but not getting the data in observer.

Comment: Why do want to get before save ? on order complete will also do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49042/discussion-between-rajat-kara-and-vishwas-bhatnagar).

Comment: i have checked with getData function i am getting other data apart from  my custom field data

Comment: Share your code in question and also for  how are you saving custom field data

Comment: please check the updated code in question.

Comment: Added a link in answer you can get idea from that how to retrive

Answer (score 4):

you can use `sales_order_invoice_save_after`(if you want to be sure the order is paid) or `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` (after order success )

**config.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_invoice_save_after">
    <observer name="inteceptafterinvoice" instance="Mycomapny\Inventoryrationing\Observer\Afterinvoice" />
</event>
```

**Afterinvoice.php**

```
class Afterinvoice implements ObserverInterface {

       public function execute(Observer $observer) 
       {
          $_event = $observer->getEvent();
          $_invoice = $_event->getInvoice();
          $_order = $_invoice->getOrder();
          $addInfo= $_order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
          [...]
          // your To insert data in another table
          [...]
        }
    }
```

For more info refer to this [link](https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/set-payment-additional-data-magento-2)